# Why can't I use match method twice in if...else construction?

Tags: javascript

My code return an error and I don't understand why.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){

        
        if(string[i].match(/a/)){
            final += 1
        }  else if (string[i].match(/A/) && string[i - 1].match(/A/)){
            final += 1
        } else if (string[i].match(/A/)){
            final += 2
        }
    }
```

```
else if (string[i].match(/A/) && string[i - 1].match(/A/)){
                                               ^

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')
>     at typist (c:\Users\123\Desktop\JavaScriptLearningProjects\27_06_2023.js:827:59)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\123\Desktop\JavaScriptLearningProjects\27_06_2023.js:837:13)
>     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
>     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
>     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error is occurring because string[i - 1] is undefined when i is 0. To fix the issue, start the loop from index 1:

```
  for (let i = 1; i < string.length; i++){
    if (string[i].match(/a/i)){
        final += 1;
    } else if (string[i].match(/A/i) && string[i - 1].match(/A/i)){
        final += 1;
    } else if (string[i].match(/A/i)){
        final += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: 10 answers, some of them lengthy, with an average interval of less than 11 minutes looks like the typical [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) workflow. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785242/can-we-control-js-with-the-help-of-css-properties-is-that-possible/76785504#76785504) had the slip-up *"my last update in September 2021"*.

Answer (score 2):

`string[i - 1]` gives `undefined` at the start of the for loop when `i` is `0` (`string[-1]`).

`undefined` doesn't have a `match` method thus the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match') at
```